# Use of _would_ in news article

Tags: grammar, will-would

The following quote is from an article in the New York Times about D. Trump’s new budget, which can be found [here](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/16/opinion/mr-trumps-tear-down-budget.html?_r=0).

> Hardest hit would be the Environmental Protection Agency, with a cut
>   of 31 percent. These cuts would end climate change research — a global
>   setback. They would eliminate money to carry out President Obama’s
>   plan to reduce carbon dioxide emissions from coal-fired plants — the
>   centerpiece of his strategy to combat global warming. They also would
>   disadvantage states that went for Mr. Trump. For Wisconsin and
>   Michigan, for example, the budget would zero out initiatives to
>   restore the Great Lakes. For Virginia, it would end restoration of
>   Chesapeake Bay, whose watershed affects Pennsylvania also. Farm
>   states, which largely supported Mr. Trump, would face a 21 percent
>   reduction in the Department of Agriculture.

I am puzzled by the repeated and consistent use of the conditional modal verb *would* in the above paragraph. What meaning is it supposed to convey? If replaced by *will* it would imply some level of certainty on the author’s part about his inferences. Is the author therefore communicating his non-conviction in using *would*? If say, he is not sure, won’t it be better to use *may* or *might* instead, so as to alert the reader about this? Or is the nuance in these statements clear to a native speaker?

Comment: @marcellothearcane I see there is an overlap, but I see that that question is quite broad. I also would like to have a clarification on whether the colloquial usage of _would_ applied to hypothetical scenarios is suitable here, seeing the rigour expected in news reporting.

Comment: Perhaps it's because it discusses a budget *proposal* (for 2018), not an actual budget (which BTW is also no more than a plan).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it fails to point out that this article covers possible rather than enacted legislation. This is a standard usage of the modal 'would'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the article, they're talking about a budget *proposal*. Using "*will*" would not only indicate certainty from the author about their predictions, but also indicate the author is certain the budget will be enacted... Because the paper is describing consequences of the budget being enacted and being the law of the land, i.e. things that will not happen (...or won't be *consequences of the budget being enacted* at least if you want to nitpick) if the budget doesn't get enacted in the first place.

"May" or "Might" in this context *would* describe uncertainty about the author's predictions; "would" is basically saying "*If* the bill passes these things *will* happen". (the same way I used "would" myself in the previous sentence).

Comment: Modal usages, especially the central ones such as this example uses, have been covered here before on numerous occasions. Please don't ignore close-votes without checking.